# Header issue does not load the right one

Tags: php, if-statement, header

Hi so i have couple of headers that have different menus for different users  and my code is

```
if (isset($_SESSION["role"])== "engineer" or isset($_SESSION["role"])!="admin") {
    include 'engineerheader.php';
  }else if (isset($_SESSION["role"])!= "engineer" or isset($_SESSION["role"])=="admin") {
    include 'adminheader.php';

 } else{
    include 'workerheader.php';
  }
```

When i log in as admin and open from the menu the worker site it shows me the engineer menu. I tried different ways of IF statements but no luck. Also if there is only one include header it works as it should but i want the admin user to have access to all sites and keep the header for the admin not to be changed when it goes to worker site with the engineer header.
Thank you for your patience and fast response.

Thanks

Comment: `isset` returns true or false, it will never equal "engineer" or any of the other strings…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question only 1 include should be needed and which one depends on the role set in the session variable named `role`. That said, this should work for you.

```
$role = ($_SESSION["role"] ?? '');
if ($role == 'engineer') {
    include 'engineerheader.php';
  } else if ($role == 'admin') {
    include 'adminheader.php';
 } else {
    include 'workerheader.php';
  }
```

You could also do it with a `switch` statement which would make it easier to modify if additional roles are needed or are taken away.

```
$role = ($_SESSION["role"] ?? '');
switch ($role) {
    case 'engineer':
        include 'engineerheader.php';
        break;
    case 'admin':
        include 'adminheader.php';
        break;
    default:
        include 'workerheader.php';
}
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score -1):

Isset is useless if you compare variabile to string! If $_SESSION["role"] is equal to "engineer" automatically is isset

```
if ($_SESSION["role"] == "engineer" or $_SESSION["role"]!="admin") {
    include 'engineerheader.php';
  }else if ($_SESSION["role"] != "engineer" or $_SESSION["role"]=="admin") {
    include 'adminheader.php';

 } else{
    include 'workerheader.php';
  }
```

Comment: Your answer fails to take into account no role being set at all. The first if will throw an error.